# How to cache react component fetches?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say you have a component like this:

```
function MyComponent({ index }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      const result = await fetchData(index);
      setData(result);
    })();
  }, [index]);

  return <h1>{data}</h1>;
}
```

Whenever the index changes, we will re-fetch the data and render it. How can I cache this so that we don't have to re-fetch the same index from before?

Comment: Build a simple caching layer into `fetchData`? Or export another function besides `fetchData` that does the caching and use that instead. But any solution really depends on how long you want the cached data to live and how/when `MyComponent` is rendered/destroyed.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah that makes sense, was wondering if there's a "react" way of doing it. Not sure if react memo could be used here?

Comment: Any hook based solution wouldn't survive the destruction of the component.

Comment: Actually, that would depend on how the hook is implemented, but `useMemo` wouldn't work as you wanted (if `useEffect` here doesn't do what you want either).

Answer (score 2):

You want to [**memoize**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your results, like:

```js
const cache = {};

async function memoFetch(index) {
  if (cache[index]) {
    return cache[index];
  }
  const data = fetchData(index);
  cache[index] = data;
  return data;
}


function MyComponent({ index }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      const result = await memoFetch(index);
      setData(result);
    })();
  }, [index]);

  return <h1>{data}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: And a potential improvement would be to only cache the data on success, to allow for re-fetches.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen better implementations than Tanstack's React Query. Here is an example, it combines memoization, loading indicators, stale times, cache times, and even local storage persistence. Here is a quick example:

```
  const { isLoading, isFetching, isIdle, error, data: postsData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['feed', { userId, profile }],
    queryFn: fetchInitialData,
    staleTime: 0,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4,
    refetchInterval: 1000 * 10, // refetch every 5 seconds
    refetchIntervalInBackground: false,
    refetchOnMount: "always",
    refetchOnWindowFocus: "always",
    refetchOnReconnect: "always",
    suspense: false
  });
```

For more information, check out the docs at https://tanstack.com/query/v4

Answer (score 0):

1. create a component cache Context:

`const MyComponentCacheContext = React.createContext() ;`

2.Create a component Cache Provider and give cache an intial Value of { } (empty Object) :

```
 function MyComponentCacheProvider (props){
                                            //we create this in step 3 
    const [cache,dispatch]= React.useReducer(MyComponentCacheReducer,{})
    const value =[cache,dispatch]
    return <MyComponentCacheContext value={value} {...props}/>

}
```

3.we will make the cache look like this => `{{index:data},{index:data},...}`so  create a component cache Reducer  that return the desired shape
:

```
function MyComponentCacheReducer (state,action) {
 switch(action.type){
     case 'ADD-TO-CACHE':
         return {...state,[action.index]:action.data}
     default :{
         throw new Error (`unhandled action type ${action.type}`)
     }
 }
}
```

4.let's make all the  code above  within a custome hook so  we can make  it reusable:

```
function useMyComponentCache(){
const MyContext = React.useContext(MyComponentCacheContext)
if(!MyContext){
    throw new Error (`useMyComponentCache must be within a MyComponentCacheProvider`)
}
return MyContext
}
```

5.let's  customize your Component function so we can  use the code above :

```
function MyComponent({ index }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [cache ,dispatch]= useMyComponentCache()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(cache[index]){
        return setData(cache[index])
    }else{
        //here we fetch data --then--> we store it into the cache  immedialty
          const dataFetcher=fetchData(index).then(
                                data =>{
                                    dispatch({type:'ADD-TO-CACHE',index,data})
                                    return data
                                }
                             )
        // updating state 
          const PromiseHandler =React.useCallback(
              promise=>{
                  promise.then(
                      data => {
                          setData(data)
                      },
                  )
              }
          ,[setData]) 
          // Execution-Time
         PromiseHandler(dataFetcher)
    }
   
  }, [cache,dispatch,index,PromiseHandler,setData]); // i assume that fetchData is 
  //a stable internal module so i didn t put it to the dependecies list

  return <h1>{data}</h1>;
}
```

6.rendering step :put your component within CacheProvider !!!

```
function App(){

return ( <MyComponentCacheProvider>
            <MyComponent index={0} /> 
         </MyComponentCacheProvider>
       )
}
```